# How to get the last part of '/' separated string in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a string as below

```
"hub.docker.corp.net/suite/content-install:latest"
```

I need to get the "content-install" from it..

So if any such string i need to extract the left portion of the last part

So if the string is

```
"aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eee:ff"
```

then i need only "eee"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make an attempt?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Beatrix: try:

```
echo "aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eee:ff" | awk -F'[/:]' '{print $(NF-1)}'  

awk -F'[/:]'        ##### making field separator as / and :, so in awk by default delimiter is space so I am making it according to your requirements.
'{print $(NF-1)}'   ##### now printing the $(NF-1) field which is second last field of the line.
```

Comment: Super bro..It worked..Kudos...Thanks a lot

Comment: could you please explain how this works..?

Comment: @BeatrixKiddo: Edited my question now, please mark it as correct if you think this is ok answer for you.

Comment: nice solution! (but, be aware it doesn't works for the `echo "/some" | awk -F'[/:]' '{print $(NF-1)}'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $x
aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eee:ff
echo $x |sed -r 's|(^.*)/(.*?):(.*)|\2|'
eee
```

*This is using `sed` with back referencing. Here, line is divided into chunks and the desired chunk of the line is referred in the replace field using `\2` for the second field.*

Or using `grep` :

```
echo $x |grep -oP '^.*/\K.*?(?=:)'
eee
```

*This is discarding everthing from the start of the line till last `/`. then it will print the text which is preceding `:`.*

Answer (score 2):

I would use a bit modified @PS.'s solution:

```
grep -oP '^(.*/)?\K.*?(?=:|\z)'
```

Test for some different inputs:

```
(echo "INPUT=RESULT"
while read -r from
do
    base=$(grep -oP '^(.*/)?\K.*?(?=:|\z)' <<<"$from")
    echo "$from=${base:-UNDEFINED}"
done <<'EOF') | column -s= -t
/aaa/bb:bb/fff:xx
/fff:xx
/fff:
/fff
/:xx
/
./aaa/bb:bb/fff:xx
./fff:xx
./fff:
./fff
./:xx
./
aaa/bb:bb/fff:xx
fff:xx
fff:
fff
:xx
EOF
```

prints

```
INPUT               RESULT
/aaa/bb:bb/fff:xx   fff
/fff:xx             fff
/fff:               fff
/fff                fff
/:xx                UNDEFINED
/                   UNDEFINED
./aaa/bb:bb/fff:xx  fff
./fff:xx            fff
./fff:              fff
./fff               fff
./:xx               UNDEFINED
./                  UNDEFINED
aaa/bb:bb/fff:xx    fff
fff:xx              fff
fff:                fff
fff                 fff
:xx                 UNDEFINED
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with `basename` and `cut`:

```
basename "hub.docker.corp.net/suite/content-install:latest" | cut -d':' -f1
```

`basename` will provide the whole string after the last "/" and with that `cut` command you get the string before the ":" delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "hub.docker.corp.net/suite/content-install:latest"|sed -r 's#.*/([^:]+).*#\1#'
```